# Creating a reactive and memoizable function outside of shiny context

Tags: r, shiny, memoization, reactive

I'm trying to create a "reactive and memoizable" version of an existing function by leveraging functions from `shiny` - but for usage outside of a shiny context.

The cool thing about relying on `shiny::reactive()` is that

1. it "automagically" knows about its reactive dependencies
2. it handles the decision "return cache or re-execute underlying expresssion" for us

While my approach of handing the function's **body** (instead of the function **itself**) to `shiny::reactive()` works per se, it makes me give up things that only work for functions such as `missing()` or `match.arg()`.

But I can't seem to find a way of handing the function itself to `shiny::reactive()`  while still making use of its built-in caching/memoization. To see this, note that `foo()` is actually executed **each** time we call `foo_react()` and thus no caching comes into play in the second approach

### Approach 1

```
# Preliminaries -----
library(shiny)
library(rlang)
options(shiny.suppressMissingContextError=TRUE)
shiny:::setAutoflush(TRUE)

makeReactiveBinding("x_react")
makeReactiveBinding("foo")

# Approach 1: hand foo()'s body to reactive() ----
foo <- function(x_react = get("x_react", 1)) {
  message("Executing foo()")
  x_react * 10
}

expr_inner <- quo(!!fn_body(foo))
expr_react <- quo(reactive({!!expr_inner}))
foo_react <- eval_tidy(expr_react)
print(foo_react)
#> reactive({
#>     ~{
#>         message("Executing foo()")
#>         x_react * 10
#>     }
#> })

x_react <- 1
foo_react() # Executes body of foo()
#> Executing foo()
#> [1] 10
foo_react() # Uses cached result
#> [1] 10
x_react <- 10
foo_react() # Executes body of foo()
#> Executing foo()
#> [1] 100
foo_react() # Uses cached result
#> [1] 100
```

Created on 2019-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) (v0.2.1)

### Approach 2

```
# Approach 2: handing foo() itself to reactive() -----
expr_inner <- quo(!!foo)
expr_react <- quo(shiny::reactive({!!expr_inner}))
foo_react <- eval_tidy(expr_react)
print(foo_react)
#> reactive({
#>     ~function (x_react = get("x_react", 1)) 
#>     {
#>         message("Executing foo()")
#>         x_react * 10
#>     }
#> })

x_react <- 1
foo_react()() # Executes foo()
#> Executing foo()
#> [1] 10
foo_react()() # Does NOT use cached result, but executes foo() again
#> Executing foo()
#> [1] 10
x_react <- 10
foo_react()() # Executes foo()
#> Executing foo()
#> [1] 100
foo_react()() # Does NOT use cached result, but executes foo() again
#> Executing foo()
#> [1] 100
```

Created on 2019-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) (v0.2.1)

Note that when handing the body of `foo()` to `reactive()`, we lose the ability to use things like `missing()` or `match.arg()`

```
foo <- function(x_react = get("x_react", 1), y = c("a", "b")) {
  message("Executing foo()")
  try(print(missing(x)))
  try(print(match.arg(y)))
  x_react * 10
}

# Approach 1 -----
expr_inner <- quo(!!fn_body(foo))
expr_react <- quo(reactive({!!expr_inner}))
foo_react <- eval_tidy(expr_react)

x_react <- 1
foo_react() # Executes body of foo()
#> Executing foo()
#> [1] 10

# Approach 2 -----
expr_inner <- quo(!!foo)
expr_react <- quo(shiny::reactive({!!expr_inner}))
foo_react <- eval_tidy(expr_react)

x_react <- 1
foo_react()() # Executes foo()
#> Executing foo()
#> [1] TRUE
#> [1] "a"
#> [1] 10
```

Created on 2019-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) (v0.2.1)

Strangely, trying to use `missing()` and `match.arg()` in approach 1 doesn't result in errors when running the code via `reprex::reprex()`, but it does for in interactive mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not quite understanding the rlang stuff. But could you just call the `foo()` function in a reactive expression, wrapping it in a function to pass args if needed? I tried tweaking approach 2 like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(rlang)
options(shiny.suppressMissingContextError=TRUE)
shiny:::setAutoflush(TRUE)

makeReactiveBinding("x_react")
makeReactiveBinding("foo")

foo <- function(x_react = get("x_react", 1), y = c("a", "b")) {
  message("Executing foo()")
  try(print(missing(x_react)))
  try(print(match.arg(y)))
  x_react * 10
}

foo_react <- function(...) {
  reactive({
    foo(...)
  })
}

## no args
f <- foo_react()
x_react <- 1
f()
# Executing foo()
# [1] TRUE
# [1] "a"
# [1] 10
f()
# [1] 10

x_react <- 10
f()
# Executing foo()
# [1] TRUE
# [1] "a"
# [1] 100
f()
# [1] 100

## with args
f <- foo_react(x_react = 3, y = "b")
f()
# Executing foo()
# [1] FALSE
# [1] "b"
# [1] 30
f()
# [1] 30
```

Comment: Nice! I think that's exactly what I was aiming for! Passing the dots - such a cool feature of R that really comes in handy in situations like this.